# replace Cambro dbcombo control

Tags: asp.net-4.0

I need either a version of the Cambro.Web.DbControl that will work on ASP.Net 4 or a Web Control that can extract from a database the records matching the user typing in the control and populates a dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Telerik RadControl (ComboBox)** for your requirement:

[Demo on ComboBox with Load on Demand](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx)

[LoadOnDemand Overview](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-load-on-demand-overview.html)

[Automatic LoadOnDemand Overview](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-automatic-load-on-demand.html)